# Backbone fetch not receiving server response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js, callback, fetch

I'm learning backbone and working through a mock twitter tutorial. Everything seems like it should be working, but i'm getting an undefined object at the point of trying to re-render my collection view on fetch({reset: true}).

I can see in my network resources a nicely formatted response from my rails server- [{id: 1, content: ...},{id: 2..}...] and so on. but If i stop at breakpoints throughout my code - as well as backbone's own success callback, response (or resp in bb's source code) is undefined.

Also, this is my first StackOverflow post after lurking here and solving problems from other folks questions for months! So thanks to this wonderful community.

relevant code here:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var tweets = new TweetsCollection;
    var stream = new TweetsView({collection: tweets});
    stream.render();


    $(".container").append(stream.el);
    tweets.fetch();
    stream.addAll();
    })

    var TweetsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tweet,
    url: 'tweets/recent',

    parse: function (response) {
    console.log("In Parse: " + response.length) //this logs "In Parse: 0"
    return response;
    }
    })

    var TweetsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: JST['backbone/templates/tweetsTemplate'],

    tagName: "section",

    id: 'tweets-container',

    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll)
    },

    render: function(){

        this.$el.html(this.template());

    return this;
    },

  addOne: function(tweet){
    debugger
    var view = new TweetView({model: tweet});
    view.render();
    this.$el.find('#tweets-container').prepend(view.el);
    console.log("addOne this: " + this);
    return this;
  },

  addAll: function(){
    console.log('adding all')
    debugger    //this.collection.length === 0
    this.collection.each(function(tweet){
        this.addOne(tweet);
    }, this);
    return this;
    }

    })
```

I can include my tweet model or view if needed- didn't seem relevant here but i've been staring at this code for a few hours so i'm biased.

Comment: I  haven't looked at the rest of your code but you should be declaring your collection before you create an instance of it.

Comment: This is just copy/pasted from various organized backbone files into one code snipped. could you be more specific?

Comment: how does the server payload looks like? is it a valid JSON serialized array?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. First off, yes, I was receiving a valid json response with success. The problem was that I was using the rails-backbone gem, which [installs its own backbone library with an custom Backbone.sync](http://www.coffeescriptlove.com/2011/11/backbone-on-rails-vs-backbone-rails-vs.html) method to work more nicely with rails. However, I also had put the standard backbone.js in my vendor/assets. I suspect it was clobbering rails-backbone's own implementation. Removed the vendor backbone.js and all is well.

thanks for the help all!